# How to install Selenium in a conda environment?

Tags: python, selenium, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install Selenium in a conda environment in Windows 10 with

```
conda install --name myenv selenium
```

but this returns the error

```
PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - selenium
```

How can I complete this package installation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Conda uses different channels to search for packages. You need find the package which supports Win 64

You can do that by going to below link

https://anaconda.org/search?q=selenium&sort=ndownloads&sort_order=-1&reverse=true

And you will find that this is most downloaded one

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/selenium

So execute below

```
conda install -c conda-forge --name myenv selenium
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Can conda be configured to automatically search different channels for a given package?

Comment: Look at this https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-config.html. I think you can use something like `conda config --add channels conda-forge`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Anaconda just use:

- go to anaconda command prompt
- just type `pip install selenium`

Answer (score 0):

- launch jupyter notebook
- write command `conda install selenium` in the cell and run it
- once installation is done restart the kernel