# How to ensure that Spyder runs within a conda environment?

Tags: python, spyder, conda

I created a conda environment called `testenv` in Windows 10 that contains Python 3.6 and Spyder.  I also installed Selenium using the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46137861/4945268).  I checked that these packages are installed with

```
conda list -n testenv
```

To run Spyder in that environment I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30170469/4945268) and its related comments.  So I activated the environment with

```
activate testenv
```

which modified the prompt to indicate that `testenv` is active.  Then I typed

```
spyder
```

to launch Spyder.  (When Spyder opens, my command window automatically closes, and if I open another one without closing Spyder, and I issue the command `conda info -e`, the output indicates that `testenv` is no longer active.) At this point, when I run code within Spyder that contains the line

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

the Spyder console reports

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

My questions are:

Is Spyder really running in `testenv`?  If so, why is this error being reported?  If not, what am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT: Further research turned up the aptly-named thread "[Spyder does not run in Anaconda virtual environment on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217175/spyder-does-not-run-in-anaconda-virtual-environment-on-windows-10)".  I followed the suggestion, in the accepted answer, of installing Spyder after activating the environment, but that just returned the message

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Anaconda3\envs\testenv:
#
spyder                    3.2.2                    py36_0
```

One of that answer's comments suggests using `where spyder` within the active environment to check which executables are available.  This returned

```
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder.exe
C:\Anaconda3\envs\testenv\Scripts\spyder.exe
```

So I tried starting Spyder by typing the full path of the second entry.  Spyder opened, and my program ran without errors.  **This seems to have solved the problem.**

Comment: Rather than editing your question with your solution, please add it as an answer below! :-) Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Spyder in virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170468/how-to-run-spyder-in-virtual-environment)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I issued the command `where spyder` within the active environment to check the locations of Spyder's executables. This returned

```
C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder.exe
C:\Anaconda3\envs\testenv\Scripts\spyder.exe
```

So I started Spyder by typing the full path of the second entry, and my program ran without errors.

Comment: This solution works for me, but only with 2 modifications **(A)** My env's `python.exe` is at the path `<Anaconda>\envs\<MyEnv>`, and not at the path `<Anaconda>\envs\<MyEnv>\Scripts` **(B)** My switching from one `python.exe` to another seems to take effect only if I restart Spyder's kernel, using the option `Consoles==>Restart kernel`. I might add that I'm using Spyder version 3.3.2, and Anaconda version 1.6.2

Comment: you can also look for the symbolic link created inside the environment, make a copy of it, an use it to launch spyder from wherever is convenient.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the Windows based link that is generated in the Windows menu. The steps:

1. (in anaconda:) activate testenv
2. (in anaconda testenv:) `conda install spyder`
3. Look up the windows menu "recently added", find `spyder (testenv)` and [add that to taskbar] and / or [look up the file source location]  and copy that to your desktop. In my case, the latter approach opened the directory `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Anaconda3 (64-bit)` where the spyder links for any of my environments could be found; you can then copy them to your desktop for a direct start without the need to open anaconda prompt.