# Unable to create process because python.exe & pythonw.exe under Conda environment MISSING/GONE

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, keras, spyder, conda

From [[Anaconda installer archive]](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/), I install `Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe`, I open a conda prompt. I create conda environment.

```
conda create -n keras_tensorflow_2 python=3.5
```

Activate it.

```
activate keras_tensorflow_2
```

Install Theano, Tensorflow & Keras.

```
conda install theano
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
pip install keras
```

*Although here, theano is successfully installed but does not work. But that's a different matter.

Run python & test for tensorflow inside the conda prompt.

```
python
import tensorflow
```

No error. It works.
So now I want to open using Spyder.
If I directly open Spyder, and `import tensorflow` inside the IPython, error shows:

> ImportError: No module named tensorflow

So what I did that work is

1. Open Anaconda Navigator
2. Anaconda Navigator>Environments. Click keras_tensorflow_2 environment. [Pic_1]
3. Anaconda Navigator>Home. At dropdown menu for "Applications on", choose tensorflow_2. Install Spyder. [Pic_2]

Then, open Spyder from Start Menu. Windows Security Alert pop up. Click Allow access. [Pic_3] . Test tensorflow, still not working.

So have to go back to Conda Prompt. Type

```
activate tensorflow_2
spyder
```

Conda prompt will automatically close and Spyder will automatically open. Import Tensorflow. **Finally WORKS!**

Up until this point, the folder `Anaconda3>envs>tensorflow_2` still has python.exe and pythonw.exe as show here [Pic_4].

**HOWEVER**, once I close/restart Spyder, the folder `Anaconda3>envs>tensorflow_2`automatically has MISSING python.exe and pythonw.exe. [Pic_5] I don't know why this would happen. So I can no longer use this environment. When I tried to 'Open with IPython' through anaconda navigator [Pic_1], error:

> Unable to create process using
>   'C:\Anaconda3\envs\keras_tensorflow_2\python.exe
>   C:\Anaconda3\envs\keras_tensorflow_2\Scripts\ipython-script.py -i'

And every time I want to use Tensorflow, I have to recreate the environment. Any advice please? Thank you.

All pictures available here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6eS8bjSwwBLSzFRTFVHdG9zTTA

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it. Python.exe and Pythonw.exe still missing. Maybe it actually doesn't matter them being missing. I don't know.

Anyway, when inside conda prompt, if I navigate to my specific environment's Script, activate the environment and then run Spyder from there, it will work.

```
cd C:\Anaconda3\envs\keras_tensorflow_2\Scripts
activate keras_tensorflow_2
spyder
```

Reference: [How to ensure that Spyder runs within a conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142967/how-to-ensure-that-spyder-runs-within-a-conda-environment)