# how to start spyder in a new conda environment?

Tags: python, windows, conda, virtual-environment

I have a .yaml conda environment file, which contains a few packages

```
name: myEnv
channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- numpy=1.12.1=py27_0
- pandas=0.20.1=np112py27_0
- scikit-learn=0.18.1=np112py27_1
 # and more
```

Then I have created a new environment from this file:

```
conda env create -f myfile.yml
```

Everything runs fine, and the envorinment is created.
I can see it under

```
conda env list
```

I can `activate` it, and run `python` in the CLI within it and the libraries are there as expected.

However, if I try to run spyder from the CLI using any of the following

```
(myEnv) spyder 
(myEnv) spyder --new-instance
(myEnv) spyder --defaults
(myEnv) spyder --reset
```

I get the following error message:

[image]

and nothing as  traceback in the cmd.exe.

Comment: Did you install spyder into the environment?

Comment: yes it was in the list of packages included

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ensure that Spyder runs within a conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142967/how-to-ensure-that-spyder-runs-within-a-conda-environment)