# zipline cannot be imported into environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, zipline

I have installed zipline (from Quantopian) to be able to backtest my investement
strategies.

However I cannot import zipline or any of its components into my Spyder IDE.

If it has any bearing on this issue I am using anaconda's Spyder v.3.2.8 64bit IDE for development and its integrated console for direct output. I created the environment 'env_zipline' and activated it.

as part of an earlier attempt I created an environment

```
conda create -n dev && activate dev

conda install -c Quantopian zipline (it seemed alright with no apparant fails)
conda create -n env_zipline python=3.5
activate env_zipline
```

My sources look like so

```
conda config --show-sources

(env_zipline) C:\Users\Morten>conda config --show-sources
==> C:\Users\Morten\.condarc <==
ssl_verify: True
channels:
  - defaults
```

---

Can anyone help me with getting zipline working and importing properly

My installed conda packages

```
(env_zipline) C:\Users\Morten>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
certifi                   2018.8.24                py35_1
chardet                   3.0.4                     <pip>
Cython                    0.28.5                    <pip>
idna                      2.7                       <pip>
Logbook                   1.4.0                     <pip>
lxml                      4.2.4                     <pip>
numpy                     1.15.1                    <pip>
pandas                    0.22.0                    <pip>
pandas-datareader         0.6.0                     <pip>
patsy                     0.5.0                     <pip>
pip                       10.0.1                   py35_0
python                    3.5.6                he025d50_0
python-dateutil           2.7.3                     <pip>
pytz                      2018.5                    <pip>
requests                  2.19.1                    <pip>
requests-file             1.4.3                     <pip>
requests-ftp              0.3.1                     <pip>
scipy                     1.1.0                     <pip>
setuptools                40.2.0                   py35_0
six                       1.11.0                    <pip>
statsmodels               0.9.0                     <pip>
urllib3                   1.23                      <pip>
vc                        14                   h0510ff6_3
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    3
wheel                     0.31.1                   py35_0
wincertstore              0.2              py35hfebbdb8_0
wrapt                     1.10.11                   <pip>
```

And because zipline is nowwhere to be found above. I am quite certain that I have an environment issue, and have tried this solution to no avail:
[How to ensure that Spyder runs within a conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142967/how-to-ensure-that-spyder-runs-within-a-conda-environment)

I also tried this solution from Googlegroups
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spyderlib/NWGlu7r7xxo/DvfqrnF2BQAJ

```
C:\Users\Morten>spyder activate env_zipline
[20520:9924:0909/173803.026:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: 5
[20520:9924:0909/173803.110:ERROR:cache_util.cc(134)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local
tWebEngine\Default\GPUCache to C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\Spyder\QtWebEngine\Default\old_GPUCache_000
[20520:9924:0909/173803.110:ERROR:cache_creator.cc(134)] Unable to create cache
[20520:9924:0909/173803.110:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(570)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
```

But this also failed. Spyder opens - but I still cannot import zipline

Under the env_zipline I do have zipline files

```
C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\Scripts>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows10_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 8FA8-3C60

 Directory of C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\Scripts

09-09-2018  09:51    <DIR>          .
09-09-2018  09:51    <DIR>          ..
26-08-2018  23:57                74 2to3-script.py
21-07-2018  03:54            40.960 2to3.exe
22-05-2017  23:57               110 alembic-script.py
22-05-2017  23:57            74.752 alembic.exe
25-07-2018  03:33               216 chardetect-script.py
21-07-2018  03:54            40.960 chardetect.exe
08-08-2018  16:44               215 cygdb-script.py
06-08-2018  20:28            40.960 cygdb.exe
08-08-2018  16:44               236 cython-script.py
06-08-2018  20:28            40.960 cython.exe
08-08-2018  16:44               216 cythonize-script.py
06-08-2018  20:28            40.960 cythonize.exe
27-08-2018  19:51               225 easy_install-script.py
21-08-2018  00:23            40.960 easy_install.exe
03-07-2018  22:51               156 f2py.bat
09-09-2018  09:48               823 f2py.py
26-08-2018  23:57                72 idle-script.py
21-07-2018  03:54            40.960 idle.exe
15-08-2018  20:18               208 mako-render-script.py
06-08-2018  20:28            40.960 mako-render.exe
20-04-2018  14:23               207 pip-script.py
16-04-2018  18:25            40.960 pip.exe
16-06-2018  10:22               215 pt2to3-script.py
15-06-2018  21:11            40.960 pt2to3.exe
16-06-2018  10:22               215 ptdump-script.py
15-06-2018  21:11            40.960 ptdump.exe
16-06-2018  10:22               217 ptrepack-script.py
15-06-2018  21:11            40.960 ptrepack.exe
16-06-2018  10:22               215 pttree-script.py
15-06-2018  21:11            40.960 pttree.exe
26-08-2018  23:57                57 pydoc-script.py
21-07-2018  03:54            40.960 pydoc.exe
15-05-2018  19:01               204 wheel-script.py
09-05-2018  00:26            40.960 wheel.exe
09-09-2018  09:50               431 zipline-script.py
17-07-2018  02:45            74.752 zipline.exe
08-09-2018  13:39    <DIR>          __pycache__
              36 File(s)        768.216 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  86.642.364.416 bytes free
```

After not being able to import zipline after the install through conda, I
decided to install through pip, and here I get a lot of dependancy errors.

---

```
      Running setup.py clean for zipline
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cyordereddict ... error
      Complete output from command C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
    __file__='C:\\Users\\Morten\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e0a7t_am\\cyordereddict\\setup.py';f=getattr(tok
    pen', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdis
    d C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-pg4nv8vu --python-tag cp35:
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict
      copying python3\cyordereddict\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict
      copying python3\cyordereddict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\benchmark
      copying python3\cyordereddict\benchmark\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\benchmark
      copying python3\cyordereddict\benchmark\magic_timeit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\benchmark
      copying python3\cyordereddict\benchmark\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\benchmark
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\test
      copying python3\cyordereddict\test\test_cyordereddict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\test
      copying python3\cyordereddict\test\test_ordereddict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\test
      copying python3\cyordereddict\test\_mapping_tests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\test
      copying python3\cyordereddict\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\test
      running build_ext
      building 'cyordereddict._cyordereddict' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visuals
    rosoft.com/downloads/

      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for cyordereddict
      Running setup.py clean for cyordereddict
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for bottleneck ... error
      Complete output from command C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
    __file__='C:\\Users\\Morten\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e0a7t_am\\bottleneck\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokeni
    ', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_w
    :\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-tgb8l3w_ --python-tag cp35:
      No Bottleneck unit testing available.
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck
      copying bottleneck\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck
      copying bottleneck\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\benchmark
      copying bottleneck\benchmark\autotimeit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\benchmark
      copying bottleneck\benchmark\bench.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\benchmark
      copying bottleneck\benchmark\bench_detailed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\benchmark
      copying bottleneck\benchmark\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\benchmark
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\slow
      copying bottleneck\slow\move.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\slow
      copying bottleneck\slow\nonreduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\slow
      copying bottleneck\slow\nonreduce_axis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\slow
      copying bottleneck\slow\reduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\slow
      copying bottleneck\slow\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\slow
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\src
      copying bottleneck\src\template.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\src
      copying bottleneck\src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\src
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\tests
      copying bottleneck\tests\input_modifcation_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\tests
      copying bottleneck\tests\list_input_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\tests
      copying bottleneck\tests\move_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\tests
      copying bottleneck\tests\nonreduce_axis_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\tests
      copying bottleneck\tests\nonreduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\tests
      copying bottleneck\tests\reduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\tests
      copying bottleneck\tests\scalar_input_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\tests
      copying bottleneck\tests\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\tests
      copying bottleneck\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck\tests
      copying bottleneck\LICENSE -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bottleneck
      running build_ext
      building 'bottleneck.reduce' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visuals
    rosoft.com/downloads/

      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for bottleneck
      Running setup.py clean for bottleneck
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for bcolz ... error
      Complete output from command C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
    __file__='C:\\Users\\Morten\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e0a7t_am\\bcolz\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, '
    en)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel
    rs\Morten\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-hwr_ralq --python-tag cp35:
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      copying bcolz\arrayprint.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      copying bcolz\attrs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      copying bcolz\chunked_eval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      copying bcolz\ctable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      copying bcolz\defaults.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      copying bcolz\py2help.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      copying bcolz\py2help_tests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      copying bcolz\toplevel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      copying bcolz\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      copying bcolz\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      copying bcolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz\tests
      copying bcolz\tests\all.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz\tests
      copying bcolz\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz\tests
      copying bcolz\tests\test_attrs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz\tests
      copying bcolz\tests\test_carray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz\tests
      copying bcolz\tests\test_carray_objects.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz\tests
      copying bcolz\tests\test_ctable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz\tests
      copying bcolz\tests\test_ndcarray.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz\tests
      copying bcolz\tests\test_queries.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz\tests
      copying bcolz\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz\tests
      copying bcolz\carray_ext.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\bcolz
      running build_ext
      skipping 'bcolz\carray_ext.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
      building 'bcolz.carray_ext' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visuals
    rosoft.com/downloads/

      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for bcolz
      Running setup.py clean for bcolz
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for toolz ... done
      Stored in directory: C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\f4\0c\f6\ce6b2d1aa459ee97cc3c0f82236302bd
    700219463
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe ... done
      Stored in directory: C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\33\56\20\ebe49a5c612fffe1c5a632146b16596f
    8661e4e46
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Mako ... done
      Stored in directory: C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\15\35\25\dbcb848832ccb1a4b4ad23f529badfd3
    17f7ca510
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for sqlalchemy ... done
      Stored in directory: C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\2b\e7\bc\03c832ebc5c8f34a4ddab35f1bc812fe
    47d6af2c9
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for intervaltree ... done
      Stored in directory: C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\6b\cf\b0\f7ef2d0f504d26f3e9e70c2369e57255
    d528fcbc5
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lru-dict ... error
      Complete output from command C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
    __file__='C:\\Users\\Morten\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e0a7t_am\\lru-dict\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize
     open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_whe
    Users\Morten\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-wzw6dnx8 --python-tag cp35:
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visuals
    rosoft.com/downloads/

      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for lru-dict
      Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for empyrical ... done
      Stored in directory: C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\83\14\73\34fb27552601518d28bd0813d75124be
    152c69112
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for trading-calendars ... done
      Stored in directory: C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\ec\f9\7b\b6b1adfae7a887e281685fe8ef92f429
    2937557e7
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for requests-ftp ... done
      Stored in directory: C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\2a\98\32\37195e45a3392a73d9f65c488cbea30f
    ef4d6b020
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for wrapt ... done
      Stored in directory: C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\48\5d\04\22361a593e70d23b1f7746d932802efe
    6a74f321e
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-editor ... done
      Stored in directory: C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\36\e0\98\ba386b125a00ea9dd52e2c16aa2ec0ad
    bfe2e001d
    Successfully built toolz MarkupSafe Mako sqlalchemy intervaltree empyrical trading-calendars requests-ftp wrapt
    ditor
    Failed to build zipline cyordereddict bottleneck bcolz lru-dict
    Installing collected packages: Logbook, pytz, numpy, idna, urllib3, chardet, requests, six, requests-file, scip
    -dateutil, pandas, requests-ftp, lxml, wrapt, pandas-datareader, patsy, statsmodels, Cython, cyordereddict, bot
    contextlib2, decorator, networkx, numexpr, bcolz, click, toolz, multipledispatch, MarkupSafe, Mako, sqlalchemy,
    ditor, alembic, sortedcontainers, intervaltree, lru-dict, empyrical, tables, trading-calendars, zipline
      Running setup.py install for cyordereddict ... error
        Complete output from command C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
    e;__file__='C:\\Users\\Morten\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e0a7t_am\\cyordereddict\\setup.py';f=getattr(t
    'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" in
    ecord C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-m2s0wnon\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-man
    mpile:
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict
        copying python3\cyordereddict\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict
        copying python3\cyordereddict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\benchmark
        copying python3\cyordereddict\benchmark\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\benchmark
        copying python3\cyordereddict\benchmark\magic_timeit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\benchmark
        copying python3\cyordereddict\benchmark\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\benchmark
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\test
        copying python3\cyordereddict\test\test_cyordereddict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\test
        copying python3\cyordereddict\test\test_ordereddict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\test
        copying python3\cyordereddict\test\_mapping_tests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\test
        copying python3\cyordereddict\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\cyordereddict\test
        running build_ext
        building 'cyordereddict._cyordereddict' extension
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visua
    icrosoft.com/downloads/

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\
    orten\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-e0a7t_am\\cyordereddict\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(_
    code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\
    pData\Local\Temp\pip-record-m2s0wnon\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed w
     code 1 in C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e0a7t_am\cyordereddict\
    You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(env_zipline) C:\Users\Morten>pip install "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools"
Invalid requirement: 'Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", li
 __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1632, in p
g
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1622, in p
g
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _
che
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3395, in p
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1383, in _
che
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3183, in p
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 10), (line:1, col:11)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 25
m_line
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "C:\Users\Morten\Anaconda3\envs\env_zipline\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", li
 __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'Visual C'"
```

---

I am at a loss, and really need help.

Can anyone guide me with dealing with these environments and getting zipline to import properly?

Answer (score 0):

Use this odd link to Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools, worked for me:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe.

[image: Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools]

That's from [Pip error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951456/pip-error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required)