# ImportError: No module named 'selenium' - need to run setup.py

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

**I am a beginner, I apologize in advance for any ambiguity in my explanation**

**Python**: Python 3.7.4

**Console used**: Anaconda Command Prompt

**Info**: I am using a work computer and work network, which has a firewall preventing me from using "pip" commands to install anything. I downloaded Selenium from their webpage

## Description of the problem

I have a python script that utilizes Selenium to web-scrape a website. Every time I restart my computer and I launch the script, I get `ImportError: No module named 'selenium'`

The temporary solution I have found for this problem is running the `setup.py` script within the Selenium folder, and then running the `install` command.

However, this temporary solution is problematic as I wish to start the script at a predetermined time using TASK SCHEDULER. From my futile attempts, when I try to run the original script via TASK SCHEDULER (no .bat file, but the .py file), I get the problem stated in the title, despite having "installed" the `setup.py` previously.

Does anyone know what this problem is due to? I have tried changing the location of the Selenium Folder to no avail.

**FYI:** The file path where I have saved all Selenium related files is ('X's used for confidentiality reasons):

F:\DEFI-TAU-CLI-XXX-FCE-XXX\XXX_XX_XXXX\XX XXXXX XXXXXXXX\Scraping Python\PYTHON - Code XXXX\Selenium\selenium-3.141.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Selenium in a conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137219/how-to-install-selenium-in-a-conda-environment)

Comment: it doesn't unfortunately @JammyDodger :(

Answer (score 1):

Python is not able to find the selenium files that you have in your F drive.

Update the PATH environment variable to include your selenium file directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could update the path environment variable by getting into the advanced system settings > environment variables 
Or you could uninstall the anaconda navigator and while reinstalling check the first box which says Add anaconda to PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Run this and ensure your custom path is listed there:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

If it isn't there, you could add it with:

```
sys.path.append('>>>your custom path here<<<')
```