# How can I install selenium package in anaconda?

Tags: selenium, anaconda

I want to know how I can install selenium package on anaconda software

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Selenium in a conda environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137219/how-to-install-selenium-in-a-conda-environment)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium may be installed through anaconda by running the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge selenium
```

You may find the original instructions [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/selenium).

I believe that a similar question was also asked in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46137219/how-to-install-selenium-in-a-conda-environment), maybe you'd want to have a look.